# Argument bottleneck python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using pool.apply_async to parallelize my code. One of the arguments I am passing in is a set that I have stored in memory. Given I am passing in a pointer to the set (rather than the set itself) does multiprocessing make copies of the set for each CPU or is the same reference passed to each CPU? I assume that given the set is stored in memory, each CPU would receives it's own set. If that is not the case, would this be a bottleneck since each CPU would request the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in principle, if you create tasks for new processes, the data has to be copied over to the new processes, as the processes don't share memory (compared to threads). The details vary a bit from Operating System to Operating System (i.e. fork vs spawn) but in general the data has to be copied over.

Whether that is the bottleneck depends a bit on how much computation you are actually doing in the processes vs the amount of data that has to be transferred over to the child processes. I suggest to measure the times: (1) process start triggered by parent, (2) actual start of computation inside the child process and (3) end of computation. That should give you roughly the ramp-up (2-1) and the computation (3-2). With these numbers you can judge best if IO is the bottleneck or computation.